# Unable to understand the logic of contramap in Writes

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

I am not able to understand how `contramap` works when writing a `case class` with a single field as `json`.

say I have a case class and I want to create its json

```
case class SomeThingContainer (something:SomeThing)
```

I would write its `write` as follows:

```
 implicit val somethingContainerWrites:Writes[SomeThingContainer] = (
    (JsPath \ "something").write[Something]
 ).contramap{(somethingContainer:SomeThingContainer)=>somethingContainer.something}
```

If I have a model as follows, 
    val somethingContainerVariable = SomethingContainer(something)

Somewhere in the application, I would call `toJson[SomeThingContainer]` to convert the model into `Json`. This would look for implicit `Writes[SomeThingContainer]` which would be `somethingContainerWrites`. From here, how is the `JSON` getting created? I could somewhat understand how `unapply _` works if there are multiple fields but I am not able to comprehend how `contramap` does its magic.

Comment: check this out: http://sadache.tumblr.com/post/30955704987/applicatives-are-too-restrictive-breaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contramap` is used for composing functors.

A `Writes` is a (contravariant) functor `X => JsValue`. (it knows how to create a JsValue from a given X)

Apparently, you already have defined a `Writes[Something]` somewhere (since you're calling `JsPath.write[Something]` which implicitly requires it).

Inside the parens, you create a new `Writes[Something]` which just uses the former to write a `Something` to a different path in a JSON object.

Now, to be able to create a `JsValue` from a `SomeThingContainer` all you need to do is to convert the `SomeThingContainer` to a `Something` -- since you already have a `Writes[Something]` at hand -- and use that.

This is what the contramap call does: from the `Writes[Something]` you have defined it creates a new `Writes[SomeThingContainer]` which, when given a `SomeThingContainer`, first calls the given "conversion function" producing a `Something`. Then, it calls the `Writes[Something]` with that.

To illustrate, what contramap does:

```
Writes[X]: Functor[X => JsValue]
C: Y => X
Writes[X].contramap(C) <==> Writes[Y]: Functor[Y => X => JsValue]
```